# Under CCPA are we required to provide salt cryptography on request?

Tags: ccpa

Basically a cryptography salt is a unique code associated with each password  which is used for security purposes.

There doesn't seem to be anything worthwhile a user can do with it. If someone just gets the salt it is still difficult for him to crack open who is the user. Is it personal information just because it is associated with the account ? Must we give it according to CCPA ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but there would be no harm in disclosing the consumer's hashed password including a salt to the consumer upon a verified request.

The CCPA defines Personal Information as “information that identifies, relates to, describes, is reasonably capable of being associated with, or could reasonably be linked, directly or indirectly, with a particular consumer or household”. The CCPA goes on to provide a non-exhaustive list of examples of personal information, none of which would match the concept of a salt.

A salt is a random value that is used to strengthen hash functions. It is usually encoded into a password hash, which in turn is associated with a consumer. It could be argued that the salt could be used as a pseudonymous or probabilistic identifier and would therefore be personal information.

However, this view is unrealistic. The salt relates to the hashing method, not to the consumer. If the hashed password is changed, a new random salt would be chosen. The salt is completely useless outside of the context of the password hash, in particular without the database containing both password hashes and other personal information. There might be an argument that the salt is “deidentified”.